# After deleting bunch of symbolic links, folder became inaccessible

Tags: windows, windows-10, ntfs, symbolic-link

I've created multiple symbolic links (pointing to existing files) using `mklink` command, and then proceeded to delete them (ONLY symbolic links themselves, target files still do exist) using Windows Explorer.

The parent directory where symlinks resided now became inaccessible, I cant navigate inside the folder using Explorer, cant open Security tab, cant delete it. I've also launched cmd.exe with SYSTEM user (`psexec64 -i -h -s cmd.exe`) and tried to `takeown` and `rmdir` the directory, to no avail (`Access denied`). The directory itself is not a symlink, just an ordinary directory.

**What is this curse and how to fight it?**

It seems like file system entry for this directory has become invalid as a result of deleting symlinks (Directory contained only symlinks, nothing else).

UPDATE: I've tried to reproduce it in different directory:

```
mkdir C:\SymLinksHere\
cd C:\SymLinksHere\
mklink FileA.txt "D:\Other\FileA.txt"
mklink FileB.txt "D:\Other\FileB.txt"
```

Then deleted files using Windows Explorer, directory is okay. Looks like this is not reproducible.

UPDATE 2:

I've restarted machine to run `chkdsk C: /F` (as suggested by [DOBRESCU_Mihai](https://superuser.com/users/1018743/dobrescu-mihai)), and, surprise: the directory is gone! Chkdsk log does not contain any indication of any "errors fixed", but there are some "Cleaning up 3020 unused index entries":

```
Checking file system on C:
The type of the file system is NTFS.


A disk check has been scheduled.
Windows will now check the disk.                         

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  1085952 file records processed.                                                         
File verification completed.
  19690 large file records processed.                                    
  0 bad file records processed.                                      

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  1043 reparse records processed.                                       
  1541940 index entries processed.                                                        
Index verification completed.
  0 unindexed files scanned.                                         
  0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.                     
  1043 reparse records processed.                                       

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Cleaning up 3020 unused index entries from index $SII of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 3020 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 3020 unused security descriptors.
Security descriptor verification completed.
  227995 data files processed.                                            
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  36066240 USN bytes processed.                                                            
Usn Journal verification completed.

Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.

 243193677 KB total disk space.
 142111640 KB in 839896 files.
    475496 KB in 227996 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
   1202953 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
  99403588 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
  60798419 total allocation units on disk.
  24850897 allocation units available on disk.

Internal Info:
00 92 10 00 f9 31 10 00 0c 2f 1c 00 00 00 00 00  .....1.../......
1c 02 00 00 f7 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

Windows has finished checking your disk.
Please wait while your computer restarts.
```

While how and why it happened still remains mystery, issue is resolved.

Comment: Can you navigate to the physical path of the directory it's symbolic link links to?

Comment: @JW0914 The directory itself is not a symbolic link, items it contained were symlinks.

Comment: Have you tried running an Operating System Command similar to `ChkDsk C: /F` and see what it is saying?

Comment: Please include in your question the output of the following: `icacls C:\Directory\Path` and `cmd /c dir /a:d h s l C:\Parent\Directory\Path`.  For the latter, only include the output line for the directory-in-question.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai Thanks for your suggestion, looks like chkdsk managed to fix it. Why and how the problem occurred still remains a mystery.

Comment: Glad to be of your service, @George Chakhidze. File Systems are not perfect. Sometimes unwanted things are happening. We are also using "_Symantec_"'s (formerly NORTON_Peter's) ["_Norton Utilities (2,0)16_"](https://us.norton.com/norton-utilities) Operating System Software Optimizer. We would also run its "_Check Disk_" / "_Repair Disk_" Functions in order to further investigate your Issue.